# How to fix "Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in a Xamarin.Android Binding Project (.aar)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms, zendesk

I'am currently writing a Plugin to use the Zendesk Support SDK (https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android_support_sdk/nutshell) in my Xamarin.Forms project. I wrote and tested the Plugin in Android Studio with a small Activity/UI. Now I created a Binding Project to use the .aar file inside of Xamarin. If I launch the application and access the first function I get an error code.

I have already tried to add the .jar files that gradle downloads to  ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 to the binding project, as well as removing all parameters I pass to the plugin. The last test I did was changing the build action of the binding project, currently my .aar's build action is set to "LibraryProjectZip" as recommended by the Xamarin documentation.

```java
Java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import zendesk.commonui.UiConfig;
import zendesk.core.AnonymousIdentity;
import zendesk.core.Identity;
import zendesk.core.Zendesk;
import zendesk.support.Support;
import zendesk.support.guide.HelpCenterActivity;
import zendesk.support.guide.ViewArticleActivity;
import zendesk.support.request.RequestActivity;

    public void Init () {
        try {
            // Return if Zendesk is already initialized
            if (IsInitialized()) return;

            Zendesk.INSTANCE.init (MainActivity, zendeskCredentials.zendeskUrl,zendeskCredentials.applicationId,zendeskCredentials.oauthClientId);
            Support.INSTANCE.init(Zendesk.INSTANCE);

            Identity identity = new AnonymousIdentity.Builder().withNameIdentifier(zendeskCredentials.userName).withEmailIdentifier(zendeskCredentials.userEmail).build();
            Zendesk.INSTANCE.setIdentity(identity);

            Support.INSTANCE.setHelpCenterLocaleOverride(locale);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("EXCEPTION: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

```
____________
```

```cs
Xamarin

public void Init() {
    ZendeskPlugin.Instance.Init();
}
```

This is what I get:

Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lzendesk/core/Zendesk; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "zendesk.core.Zendesk" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/de.foo.foo-25GgMgJo-hI1Hnw8TCqT-A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.foo.foo-25GgMgJo-hI1Hnw8TCqT-A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/de.foo.foo-25GgMgJo-hI1Hnw8TCqT-A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <09821b4f44794452b7d6c054ac9447f5>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <09821b4f44794452b7d6c054ac9447f5>:0

...

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer this question, but I hope this will help others to solve their problem.
Please try to install `Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib` in your Xamarin Android project. Installing the Kotlin package worked for me because I was using the `.aar` file which contains Kotlin code.

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib -Version 1.3.50.1
```